# how to get specific data from another entity with specific fields in springboot

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

SpringBoot
Student Friend List monitoring, for that created 2 model classes like `Student` and `FriendList`

```
Student->blockedList table(one to many relationship)
FriendList->student table(many to one relationship)
```

**Student table consist of**

- studentid, name, dob, school, college

**Friend table consist of**

- friendid, studentid(foreign key from student), stufid() (foreign
  key from student)

I need to retrieve the student friend details through passing (studentid),

```
{
  studentid:
   friendlist[
       { 
          stufid:
          name:
          dob:
        },
       { 
          stufid:
          name:
          dob:
        }
   ]

}
```